# Vanishing metric component?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Consider a metric $g_{\mu \nu} = \text{diag}(g_{xx},g_{yy},g_{zz})$.

Now consider another metric $h_{\mu \nu}=\partial_x g_{\mu \nu} = \text{diag}(\partial_x g_{xx} ,\partial_xg_{yy},\partial_x g_{zz})$.

But, $\partial_x g_{zz}=0$. Hence, $h_{\mu \nu} = \text{diag}(\partial_x g_{xx} ,\partial_xg_{yy},0)$.

What does it mean that the $zz$ component now is zero physically? Does this mean that $h_{\mu \nu}$ is a co-dimension 1 metric?

Comment: No, it just means that that particular metric component is independent of that coördinate.

Comment: You seem to think that $h_{\mu\nu}=\partial_x g_{\mu\nu}$ is a metric itself. This is not true because the standard partial derivative of a tensor is not a tensor anymore, so if $g_{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor, $\partial_x g_{\mu\nu}$ is not (you can check that it doesn't transform correctly under general coordinate transformations). It takes a Lie or covariant derivative to produce a tensor out of another one by differentiation.

Comment: How would I then compute the Christoffel symbols? If I disregard the $z$ direction I am effectively working with a 2d metric? @naturallyInconsistent

Comment: Your confusion is so weird that, without more context, we cannot even know where to begin to help you. Consider the spherical polar coördinates: its metric is $g_{ab}=\text{diag}(1,r^2,r^2\sin^2\vartheta)$ which is independent of $\varphi$, so that $\partial_\varphi g_{ab}=0$. Only $g_{ab}$ is a valid metric. Its derivative is not a metric at all. Christoffel symbols are another thing entirely.